# Select value base on fetch result via ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a bit of trouble with the following...

I have 2 basic select form:

```
<select id="data" onchange="getMetals(this.value)">
<option value="-1">Select a color</option>
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Blue</option>
</select>

<select id="dynaData">
<option value="-1">Please make a selection</option>
</select>
```

Now, with the first select I populate the options on the second select via "ajax", that part is working just fine, but some options from the second select have more "options"

So when the second select gets populated I get something like:

```
    <select id="dynaData">
     <option value="-1">Please make a selection</option>
     <option value="1">Raw Metal</option>
     <option value="2">Titanium</option>
     <option value="3">Steel</option>
    </select>
```

until this point the ajax is working fine, before the ajax I was using a direct SQL Query to populate the option and the output was before any other jquery, and now, I have to execute the ajax first and then a jQuery, whit this jQuery the idea is to get the value that the user is slecting so I can show some more options... the problem is that even a simple .addClass is not working. the flow is as follow:

```
HTML from PHP -- > Ajax to Populate Select boxes -- > Get Value from selected box
       ^                        ^                             ^
       |________________________|_____________________________| <-- Working
                                         ^                       ^
                                         |_______________________|  <-- Not Working
```

So the user select from the first select box, it then populate the second select box, then the user select from the second select box and there I need to get the value, but is not working...

now, at first I thought that the problem was because the ajax was getting a json data to populate the second select box, so I change it to a raw html... the HTML is formed on a second file base on the first request...

The problem is after the ajax gets triggered, but the ajax is a needed function.

The script that die every time the ajax gets executed is:

```
var hash = jQuery.noConflict();
hash("select").change(function(){
        var mSt = $(this).find("option:selected").val(); // Value from 2dn select
        if (mSt == 3){
            $("#noShow").css('border', '1px solid red');
            return false;
        } else { $("#noShow").css('border', '1px solid green'); return true; }
    });
```

I made this for better understanding, so, before the ajax this code is working fine, but after the ajax populate the second box it just die! I did a little "debug" but eveything seems to be working fine, then I thought that there may be a java conflict but no, there is no conflict at all.

I really can't figure it out, how to get the values... 
any help would be greatly appreciated...

Remember, the second box has no option's, the options are from the ajax request base on the first box... my ajax is very simple...

```
function getMetals(Metals) {
        var strURL ="ajax/metal.php?val="+Metals;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('metals').innerHTML=req.responseText;
                }
            };
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }
    }
```

Thank you for taking the time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.on` to hook up events with dynamically added elements.

Try,

```
var hash = jQuery.noConflict();

hash(document).on('change','select',function(){
        var mSt = $(this).find("option:selected").val(); // Value from 2dn select
        if (mSt == 3){
            $("#noShow").css('border', '1px solid red');
            return false;
        } else { $("#noShow").css('border', '1px solid green'); return true; }
    });
```